# How to restrict Jenkins to only repos under my Github Organization?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, github-organizations

I'm setting up a new Jenkins instance for my company. It's deployed via helm to GKE, and configured using the [Jenkins Configuration As Code Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin). We store all of our code in repositories under a Github organization.

The instance is up and running but when creating a pipeline in Jenkins, it asks for a Github Personal Access Token. This is bad because if someone leaves the company, we need to reconfigure the pipelines they set up.

I want to configure Jenkins to use an "automation" Github user's Personal Access Token.

I think it can be done using the [Github Branch Source Plugin](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/plugins/github-branch-source/) but I can't work out how to configure it using [Jenkins Configuration As Code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin).

My configuration currently looks like:

```
    JCasC:
      enabled: true
      PluginVersion: 1.11
      SupportPluginVersion: 1.11
      ConfigScripts:
        welcome-message: |
          jenkins:
            systemMessage: Welcome to our CI\CD server.  This Jenkins is configured and managed 'as code'.
        github-oauth: |
          jenkins:
            securityRealm:
              github:
                githubWebUri: "https://github.com"
                githubApiUri: "https://api.github.com"
                clientID: "<some-id>"
                clientSecret: "<some-secret>"
                oauthScopes: "read:org,user:email,repo"
        github-org-lock: |
          jenkins:
            authorizationStrategy:
              globalMatrix:
                grantedPermissions:
                  - "Overall/Administer:<some-org>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a credential should solve your problem I think.

This is how I'm managing credentials on JCasC:

`credentials:
  system:
    domainCredentials:
      - credentials:
        - usernamePassword:
            scope:    GLOBAL
            id:       cred-id
            username: "<github_username>"
            password: "<github_access_token>"     # Access Token Rights: https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo,read:org,user:email,admin:repo_hook,admin:org_hook
            description: Account for Repository Discovery`